# Compare 2 columns in 2 seperate dataframes and return value of matching row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas DataFrames, `df1` contains all of my information regarding vulnerabilities in our environment, `df2` contains exceptions. Both have matching headers. I need to compare if  each line in `df1` contains both the title and tags(not exact match in every case) and return the risk of the same row.

df1: Vulnerabilities

| title | tags |
| --- | --- |
| vulnerability1 | prod,dev |
| issue2 | dev |
| issue3 | prod, repo |
| task4 | dev, repo |

df2: Exceptions

| title | tags | Risk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vuln | prod | RIS001 |
| issue | dev | RIS002 |
| note | repo | RIS003 |

End goal:
Add column to `df1` with the risk number from `df2` if `df1` contains title and tags

df1:

| title | tags | risk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vulnerability1 | prod,dev | RIS001 |
| issue2 | dev | RIS002 |
| issue3 | prod, repo | N/A or blank |
| task4 | dev, repo | N/A or blank |

I am fairly new to python, and the logic on doing this is a bit above where I am at but would shave off hours of my workday if I can get this working.

Edit: Below is what I'm trying(ignore headers and df names) but I'm not sure how to parse the entire sheet with this.

```py
df.loc[(ex['Title'].isin(df['Title']) & ex['AssociatedTags'].isin(df['Associated Tags']))]
```

Comment: And I believe you had tried something so far, please pose that as well.. Also visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Next time, please provide your data frames as code so that one can just copy paste it.

For your given data frames `df1` and `df2`:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "title": ["vulnerability1", "issue2", "issue3", "task4"],
    "tags": ["prod, dev", "dev", "prod, repo", "dev, repo"]
}) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "title": ["vuln", "issue", "note"],
    "tags": ["prod", "dev", "repo"],
    "risk": ["RIS001", "RIS002", "RIS003"]
})
```

you should first make sure that all values are upper or lower case to ensure the finding of you matches. You can decide whether this step is important or redundant for you, I just wanted to include it for the sake of completeness. To do so, you can use `str` + `lower()` or `upper()`. I do it iteratively for all columns:

```py
for col in df1.columns:
  df1[col] = df1[col].str.lower()
for col in df2.columns:
  df2[col] = df2[col].str.lower()
```

Next - and that is the important part and was already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982894/pandas-map-columns-based-on-substring) for one column - you can extract the matches of the columns containing the content of the other data frame using `extract`. Afterward, you can just merge both data frames using on the extracted columns:

```py
df1["title_merge"] = df1["title"].str.extract(f'({"|".join(df2["title"].unique())})')
df1["tags_merge"] = df1["tags"].str.extract(f'({"|".join(df2["tags"].unique())})')
pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={"title": "title_merge", "tags": "tags_merge"}), on=["title_merge", "tags_merge"], how="left")
```

Output:

```py
    title           tags        title_merge   tags_merge    risk
0   vulnerability1  prod, dev   vuln          prod          ris001
1   issue2          dev         issue         dev           ris002
2   issue3          prod, repo  issue         prod          NaN
3   task4           dev, repo   NaN           dev           NaN
```

Comment: I ran this and was getting an error, my dataframes are different sizes, dpes that matter with a merge? The Vulnerability table is like 10k plus rows in some instances and the df2 is only like 20 rows

Comment: @TimD, I need more information to help you debugging. what kind of error msg are you receiving? Which pandas version are you using (print(pd.__version__))? The size of both tables should not matter for your merge. You are merging a 10.000 k row df to a 20 rows df, right?

Comment: Exception has occurred: ValueError
Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (25572, 7)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/Users/tdDocuments/VS Code/filename.py", line 71, in <module>
    df["title_merge"] = df["Title"].str.extract(f'({"|".join(ex["Title"].unique())})')

Pandas 1.4.2