# PANDAS : map columns based on substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data-frames :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Description': ['SYD_SYDNEY AIRPORTS CORPORATION LIMITED-Aircraft Parking :Sep','SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Sep', 'SYD_SNP SECURITY SERVICES PTY LTD-Aircraft Security :Sep'
], 'Commodity_Code': ["", "", "",],  })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['Turn Cost', 'Aircraft Security'
, 'Aircraft Parking'], 'Commodity_Code': [24101900, 92121700, 78141805,],  })
```

I would like to fill in the Commodity_Code from df1 based on the item from df2 which is a part of a string in Item_Description (df1).
For example: "Turn Cost" is a part of the string : "SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Sep" so the Commodity Code would be : 24101900

The expected result would be :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First let's extract the `Item` into `df1` then we can merge to get the commodity code.

```
#df1 = df1.drop('Commodity Code',axis=1) # you don't need an empty column..
pat = '|'.join(df2['Item'].values)

df1['Item'] = df1['Item_Description'].str.extract(f"({pat})")

                                    Item_Description               Item
0  SYD_SYDNEY AIRPORTS CORPORATION LIMITED-Aircra...   Aircraft Parking
1              SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Sep          Turn Cost
2  SYD_SNP SECURITY SERVICES PTY LTD-Aircraft Sec...  Aircraft Security
```

---

```
final = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Item'],how='left')

print(final.drop('Item',axis=1))


                                    Item_Description  Commodity_Code
0  SYD_SYDNEY AIRPORTS CORPORATION LIMITED-Aircra...        78141805
1              SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Sep        24101900
2  SYD_SNP SECURITY SERVICES PTY LTD-Aircraft Sec...        92121700
```

Comment: Brilliant way of doing this! +1

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks! it's always inefficent when dealing with strings, the trick is to find the least inefficient way!

Comment: Hi, When I am using this solution : 
df1['Item'] = df1['Item_Description'].str.extract(f"({pat})") on a larger range of data I receive the below error : 
"Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1"
Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Did you change how you created the pat variable ?

Comment: I applied the solution to the existing data frame :
    pat = '|'.join(dfd_commodity['Item'].values)
    dfd_RD['Item'] = dfd_RD['Item_Description'].str.extract(f"({pat})")

KeyError: 'Item'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
---> 85     dfd_RD['Item'] = dfd_RD['Item_Description'].str.extract(f"({pat})")

Comment: What version of pandas and python are you using ?

Comment: I found where is the issue ; the issue are the brackets ()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Description': ["SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-ADQ :Sep","SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Jul","SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Aug"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ["Adhoc - Please comment","ADQ","AIMS (flight numbers in FIDSMON)"],'Commodity_Code': [24101900,46171624,24101900,]})
AIMS (flight numbers in FIDSMON) - this item is causing the issue because of the brackets but I do not know how to handle this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246453/discussion-between-toerag-and-umar-h).

Comment: ah looks like you'll need to expldoe it first can you edit your question? @toerag

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them in a `cross` join:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how='cross', suffixes=['_x', ''])
merged
```

| Item_Description | Commodity_Code_x | key | Item | Commodity_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SYD_SYDNEY AIRPORTS CORPORATION LIMITED-Aircraft Parking :Sep |  | 0 | Turn Cost | 24101900 |
| SYD_SYDNEY AIRPORTS CORPORATION LIMITED-Aircraft Parking :Sep |  | 0 | Aircraft Security | 92121700 |
| SYD_SYDNEY AIRPORTS CORPORATION LIMITED-Aircraft Parking :Sep |  | 0 | Aircraft Parking | 78141805 |
| SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Sep |  | 0 | Turn Cost | 24101900 |
| SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Sep |  | 0 | Aircraft Security | 92121700 |
| SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Sep |  | 0 | Aircraft Parking | 78141805 |
| SYD_SNP SECURITY SERVICES PTY LTD-Aircraft Security :Sep |  | 0 | Turn Cost | 24101900 |
| SYD_SNP SECURITY SERVICES PTY LTD-Aircraft Security :Sep |  | 0 | Aircraft Security | 92121700 |
| SYD_SNP SECURITY SERVICES PTY LTD-Aircraft Security :Sep |  | 0 | Aircraft Parking | 78141805 |

Filter where `Item` is a substring of `Item Description`:

```
merged[merged.apply(lambda x:x.Item_Description.__contains__(x.Item), axis=1)].drop(columns=['Commodity_Code_x', 'key'])
```

| Item_Description | Item | Commodity_Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SYD_SYDNEY AIRPORTS CORPORATION LIMITED-Aircraft Parking :Sep | Aircraft Parking | 78141805 |
| SYD_QANTAS AIRWAYS LTD-Turn Cost :Sep | Turn Cost | 24101900 |
| SYD_SNP SECURITY SERVICES PTY LTD-Aircraft Security :Sep | Aircraft Security | 92121700 |

Or if you want it within `df1`:

```
df1 = merged[merged.apply(lambda x:x.Item_Description.__contains__(x.Item), axis=1)].drop(columns=['Commodity_Code_x', 'key', 'Item'])
```

Comment: you don't need to do the key=0 psuedo keys any more with recent version of pandas.  There is a how='cross' now. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge

Comment: Thanks for this! I will add it in answer